# Can anyone find the bug in this code

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, custom-field, standardcontroller

actually I dont want to insert the record in the contacts with the help of standard "save" button, I want to use my button which will redirect to my page rather then contact detail page after saving the record to contact.I am new in SFDC please guide me. Key opration I want to perform is (""Save the record in the contact and redirect to my custom page on click of my custom buttton"")
Apex:

```
public Class Saver{

    public Saver(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    list<contact> conList=new list<contact>([SELECT Firstname, LastName, user_name__c, Password__c, email, birthdate,Permanent_Address__c, correspondence_address__c, Department,Technology__c, Date_of_joining__c from contact]);
    //con= [SELECT Firstname, LastName, user_name__c, Passsword__c, email, birthdate,Permanent_Address__c, corrospondance_address__c, Department,Technology__c, Date_of_joining__c from contact];
    public PageReference saveIt(){
        for(contact c:){

           c.lastname=c.lastname;
           c.user_name__c=c.user_name__c; 
           c.password__c=c.password__c; 
           c.firstName=c.firstname;
           c.email=c.email;
           c.Permanent_Address__c=c.Permanent_Address__c;
           c.correspondence_address__c=c.correspondence_address__c;
           c.Department=c.Department;
           c.Technology__c=c.Technology__c;
           c.Date_of_joining__c=c.Date_of_joining__c; 
           c.birthdate=c.birthdate;

           conlist.add(c);
        }

        if(conlist.size()>0){

           insert conlist;

        }
         PageReference pageRef=new PageReference('apex/predirect');
           pageRef.Setredirect(True);
           return pageRef;


    }

}
```

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Saver"  showheader="false" >
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <!-- Bootstrap -->
         <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
         <link href="//getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
         <title>BootStrapV3 on Visualforce Page by Oyecode</title>
         </head>
      <body>
      <div class="container">
      <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Employee Information">
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:inputField value="{! Contact.FirstName }"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email }"/>  
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MobilePhone }"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.birthdate }"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Permanent_address__c }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Correspondence_address__c }"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Department }"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Technology__C }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Date_of_Joining__c }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.User_Name__c }"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Password__c }"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveIt}" value="Submit" />     
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: "for(contact c:){" I think your code is missing something, this will not pass the compiler

Comment: Also these lines `c.lastname=c.lastname;` make no sense as they are assigning a value to itself. Please post the actual code you are using - as Sander mentions what you have posted won't even compile.

Comment: actually I dont want to insert the record in the contacts with the help of standard "save" button, I want to use my button which will redirect to my page rather then contact detail page after saving the record to contact.I am new in SFDC please  guide me. Key opration I want to perform is (""Save the record in the contact and redirect to my custom page on click of my custom buttton"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will solve your problem.

```
public Class Saver{

    private Contact theContact;

    public Saver(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        theContact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference saveIt(){

        PageReference pageRef;
        try{
            update theContact
            pageRef = PageReference('apex/predirect');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;
        }catch(DmlException e)
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Based on the code you posted you seem to have a poor understanding of some of the functionality / concepts in play with VF and Controllers. I'd like to help you better understand some of what is happening in your controller.

First you are using a `StandardController`, this will allow you to directly access the fields on the Contact record **without needing** an extension.  The only reason you need an extension is because you want to redirect the User to a custom page.

In your Controller you don't need to query a Contact, the StandardController has a method `getRecord()` which will return the Contact that is being accessed via the VF page.  Furthermore population of the Contact fields is being handled automatically via the VF Page / StandardController so you don't need to worry about that as well.

This line here is worrisome for a couple reasons

```
list<contact> conList=new list<contact>([SELECT Firstname, LastName, user_name__c, Password__c, email, birthdate,Permanent_Address__c, correspondence_address__c, Department,Technology__c, Date_of_joining__c from contact]);
```

- It doesn't specify a WHERE clause, thus you will query every Contact in your org.  If you have more than 50,000 Contacts you will get a Limit Exception
- SOQL Statements return a List so you don't need to pass them into the constructor.  You can simply say `List<Contact> conList = [SELECT ... ];`

Your `for loop` also has some issues

```
for(contact c:){
     c.lastname=c.lastname;
     c.user_name__c=c.user_name__c; 
     ...

     conlist.add(c);
}
```

- You don't specify anything after the `:` character.
- I'm assuming you mean it to be `for(contact c : conList){` which would iterate over every contact in the `conList` which as stated earlier would be every contact in your org.
- `c.lastname=c.lastname;` Here your assigning the same value repeatedly so no change.  Essentially your are saying 1 = 1.

You should not be inserting any contacts.

```
if(conlist.size()>0){
    insert conlist;
}
```

At this point conList has a copy of all Contacts that exist in your org, inserting them will either give an error, or result in duplication of contacts.  Since you are trying to edit an existing Contact the `update` dml statement is what you want to use.

Finally you should surround your `update` statement with `try/catch` blocks to catch any possible errors that happen (such as a required field not being entered) and show them to your user.  Returning `null` will refresh the page allowing the User to see any errors that were added.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below to insert Contact and Redirect to custom page.

Basically, what you require here to insert the Contact record and redirect to  custom page.

To Redirect, you need to use [setRedirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) method.

Also, you don't need to query any Contact record. Just create instance of Contact record and bind that instance with VF page.

Use List when you need to insert more than one Contact records.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="ContactCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages id="pgMsgId" />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Employee Information">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.FirstName }"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName }"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!saveContact}" reRender="pgMsgId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class ContactCtrl{
    public Contact contact{get;set;}

    public ContactCtrl(){
        contact = new Contact();
    }

    public Pagereference saveContact(){
        try{
            insert contact;
        }catch(Exception objEX){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,objEX.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        Pagereference pg = Page.NewPage; // Specify Page here
        pg.setRedirect(true);
       return pg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and not just a code dump.